# Publishing Scaling multiple CM servers

Tags: publishing-service, scaling

I need to create **multiple CM Servers** (behind Load Balancer) in Azure VM. I have gone through the **scaling guidelines** mentioned at:

https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/scaling-guide/scaling-scenarios/scale-horizontally/index.html#multiple-content-management-instances

But there are **no instructions** to create **single point of publishing** (i.e. only one CMS can do the publishing) as mentioned in old scaling guide at:
https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/scaling_guide_sc70_a4.pdf
(Page 28)

So my question is, is single point of publishing is still applicable with `Sitecore 9` or not?

Thanks,
Nicks

Answer (score 2):

**A) Using Publishing Service**

Sitecore 9 has XM services and only service currently available is Publishing Service. As you are using Sitecore 9, I would definitely go with this Publishing Service which is best option in scaled CMS setup.

Take a look here for further details:
https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/server-role-configuration-reference/xm-service-roles/publishing-service.html

Here is the download page for Sitecore 9 compatible Publishing Service:
https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Publishing_Service/31/Sitecore_Publishing_Service_31_Initial_Release.aspx

Take a look on Installation Guide:
https://dev.sitecore.net/~/media/B54F1A3A1BAA4B0C8DF5B41C893670F2.ashx

**B) Without Publishing Service**

When you do not want to use Publishing Service (and opt for old fashioned way :)) follow these doc articles:

1. Configuration for CM servers - https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/server-role-configuration-reference/core-roles/content-management/index.html#configure-multiple-cm-servers
2. Configuration for CD servers - https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/server-role-configuration-reference/core-roles/content-delivery.html#configure-multiple-cd-servers

Comment: Thanks for the updates. If we are not planning to use separate Publishing service and if we have 2 CM servers, then do we need to configure publishing happens from only one CMS server as mentioned in:
https://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/scaling_guide_sc70_a4.pdf (Page 28)
or you still suggest to setup separate publishing service on one of the CMS server.

Comment: Follow these two articles to achieve publishing only on one CMS in Sitecore9 (obviously configuration needs to be set up on CM servers + CD servers also):
1. Configuration for CM servers - https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/server-role-configuration-reference/core-roles/content-management/index.html#configure-multiple-cm-servers
2. Configuration for CD servers - https://doc.sitecore.net/developers/server-role-configuration-reference/core-roles/content-delivery.html

Comment: I have updated answer with same information